# Why did lego stop the Ninjago Spinjitzu Flyer and switch to the Ninjago Spinjitzu Spinner?

Tags: ninjago

A while ago Lego ran a Ninjago Flyer line of products:

[image]

Now there seems to be a 'dumbed down' version of this that doesn't fly, it just spins along the ground.

[image]

It seems like maybe there was an Health and Safety issue with the flying ones, or maybe kids were getting them lost on the roof or in the next door neighbor's yards or something. But surely that's part of what makes them so fun!

My question is: **Why did Lego stop the Ninjago Spinjitzu Flyer and switch to the Ninjago Spinjitzu Spinner?**

Comment: Possibly because getting two spinners to collide in mid air is much harder than on a 2D plane...

Comment: Maybe the popularity of Beyblade (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade) made them change? I don't know how popular they are, but one of my little cousin is a fan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flyers were released in 2015, 2 years is an average production run for LEGO sets. Note that spinners have been released before, in 2011 and 2012 with expansion packs like cards and weapons.

I think the most likely reason that the flyers were discontinued is that LEGO did not see enough marketing potential in a second wave.

As to being more "fun", that is entirely subjective. These flying plastic rings were around in my childhood as well and I hated them.
To me they seem now old fashioned compared to the myriads of flying drone toys that are available today.

**Update:** Apparently, it was a bit premature to state that the flyers line of ninjago had ended: https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Ninjago/subtheme-Dragon-Masters

Answer (score 2):

My local retailer mentioned issues with flyers getting lost as they flew away... a little too well